# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'total' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I just got back with programming and I came across this, I don't understand why I keep getting this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'total' has already been declared". When I use a different variable name, the problem doesn't occur.

This is the code that emits the error:

```
let total = 0;
function sumArray(array) {
    for (let num in array) {
        total += array[num];
    }
    return total;
}
```

When I change the variable name, the error doesn't occur

```
let sum = 0;
function sumArray(array) {
    for (let num in array) {
        sum += array[num];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

and when I place the variable total inside the function, the error doesn't occur either.

```
function sumArray(array) {
    let total = 0;
    for (let num in array) {
        total += array[num];
    }
    return total;
}
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: I don't get any error. The error may be for the lines above it. Did you define variable `total` twice in your code?

Comment: Share line # given in error  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'total'` and code written `let total = 0;` ?

Comment: The questions is missing context such as the rest of the code and error as the error is likely to be somewhere else than in the shared code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

alot of times when coding there could be invisible letters, i ran your code  on my end, see Below, i had no issues.this is only an identification that the variable total is already named in the file. unless you can provide us with more information of this error message,
In your terminal, does it tells you the where the variable "total"is named?
Can you perhaps do a quick find in your terminal by finding this hiding variable? if you are in a mac press "Command f" or windows:"ctrl f"

```
let total = 0;
function sumArray(array) {
    for (let num in array) {
        total += array[num];
    }
    return total;
}
```